# Add-on for 32 bit IE is disable after being registered?

Tags: internet-explorer, bho, add-on

I created a Browser Helper Object (an add-on for IE) and registered it for a 32 bit version of IE, but that registered add-on is not enable as I want, I have to open Add-ons manager of IE to enable it manually.

Could you please help me to make it enable as default right after being registered. This should be done because I don't think showing an instruction on how to enable that add-on manually for user to do follow is a good idea.

If you need more details about anything, please let me know!
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes against Microsoft recommendation, and most toolbars and IE extensions wouldn't do it. Take a cue from Adobe (reader and flash), Oracle's Java, DivX, Google toolbar, etc. None of these extension enable themselves on installation, but let the user do it.
However, if your extension belong to the class of SpyWare, AdsWares, or just a plain good old virus - then by all mean you want your extension to be enabled, without the user actually enabling it.

Do it here:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Settings{CLSID}\Flags (REG_DWORD)

{CLSID} is the COM clsid of your object.
Bit zero will dictate whether the extension is disabled/enabled. Will take effect after you restart IE.

Comment: Thanks, do you know the meanings of other values for Flags such as 200, 400 ...? Documentation to understand those values for Flags is also helpful to me, thanks again!